# Angular project - Why model everywhere?

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

I just started working on existing angular project. Below code is just idea of how the code is written? Everywhere they have used model (all business logic code here) like below.
I didn't get the logic behind using model like this. They clearly broken the DI rule.
If I have to inject something in model, then first I have to inject in component then I can inject in model. 
I asked the one of existing team member about this. He said "We did this to load component fast."

I am so confused, How moving all the code in separate model will help in loading component faster? Please Provide your thoughts on it.

// play.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-play',
    templateUrl: './play.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./play.component.css']
})
export class PlayComponent {
    public model: PlayModel;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private apiDataService: ApiDataService) {
        this.model = new PlayModel(apiDataService);
        this.model.initialize();
    }
}
```

// play.model.ts

```
export class PlayModel {
    public displayedColumns: string[] = [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'avatar'
    ];
    public users: Observable<IUserList>;

    constructor (private apiDataService: ApiDataService) {

    }

    public initialize() {
        this.users = this.apiDataService.getUsers();
    }

    public refresh() {
        this.users = this.apiDataService.getUsers();
    }
}
```

In html in everywhere they have used model like this

`<button mat-button (click)="model.refresh()">Refresh</button>`

why extra model everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's just an opinion. There are plenty of opinions out there.

In AngularJS, there was an Opinionated Concept of [Skinny Controllers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers) where most of the logic of Controller was moved to a Service.

Your Team is probably following the same in Angular by making your Components Skinny.

An ideal approach to have a look at this is to follow Separation of Concerns. That's what's recommended by the Angular Team as the [**Single Responsibility Principal**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility), which states **some** of the following:

> Do define one thing, such as a service or component, per file.
>
> Consider limiting files to 400 lines of code.
>
> Do define small functions
>
> Consider limiting to no more than 75 lines.

For simplicity just consider this for the Single Responsibility Principle:

1. **Component**: The only task of a Component is to present something on the UI. Or to get some User Inputs. So only this code should be written in a Component. So a Component will not have any business logic.
2. **Service**: These serves as utilities or business logic containers for your App. So anything related to that should go inside a Service.
3. **Directive**: These are generally used to enhance the behavior of your template. So anything related to that should reside in a Directive.
4. **Pipe**: Generally used for transforming the data just to present it on the UI without actually changing the data.
5. **Interface**: Use them for writing data models.

This list could go on... But hope you get the idea of what goes where.

You can consider refactoring your code accordingly.